# Segmentation fault in c++ when adding a node at the end to a linking list

Tags: c++

```
void List::insertBack(ListItemType newItem)
    {
        ListNode *p;
        ListNode *q;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            p = new ListNode;
            p -> item = newItem;
            p -> next = head;
            head = p;
        }
        else
        {
            p = new ListNode;
            q -> next = p;
            q = head;
            while (q-> next != NULL)
                {
                    q = q->next;
                };
            p -> item = newItem;
            p -> next = NULL;
        }
    }
```

I am attempting to add a node at the end of a linking list in c++. I am somewhat new to the concept so it's a bit complex to me and when I look at other answers I don't follow where they are going? What am I doing wrong to cause a segmentation fault?

Comment: ListNode *q; [SNIP] q -> next = p; <<<< q is not set, crash !

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have shown no effort to use a debugger to investigate the execution of your code, and SO is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment of:

```
q -> next = p;
```

is premature. You haven't initialized `q` yet, and it's pointing at some random value. You should move the assignment till after you've found the node after which you want to place `p`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `q->next` before you have assigned `q` first.  Your implementation should look like this instead:

```
void List::insertBack(ListItemType newItem)
{
    ListNode *p = new ListNode;
    p->item = newItem;
    p->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = p;
    }
    else
    {
        ListNode *q = head;
        while (q->next != NULL)
            q = q->next;
        q->next = p;
    }
}
```

That being said, if you add a `tail` pointer to your `List` class, inserting to the back will be greatly simplified and much more efficient:

```
void List::insertBack(ListItemType newItem)
{
    ListNode *p = new ListNode;
    p->item = newItem;
    p->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
        head = p;

    if (tail != NULL)
        tail->next = p;
    tail = p;
}
```